# Magento configurable product sku on catalog/category/view

Tags: magento

I'm sure there is a simple solution for this, however, having searched, I can't find one.

I need to list out all the configurable product skus for the current category on the catalog/category/view.phtml so i can include it in a tracking pixel.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in the view.phtml file

```
<?php
$productCollections=$_category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable');
foreach($productCollections as $p)
{
        echo $p->getSku();
}
?>
```